# How to control the js files that are load in layout, from the Controller (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

First of all, I'm a beginner in Zend Framework and maybe there is a simple way of doing this but i don't know it.

What I am trying to achieve is to load different js files (in layout head) depending on what Controller is used. 
I can't add the js files as variables to the Layout object because the layout is disabled in those Controllers.

What's the proper way to do it? Thank you.

**Edit (the code)**

In the CalendarController (using Subdigger's method):

```
    public function init()
    {
      $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

      $js = new Application_View_Helper_Javascript();
      //get an array with the basename of the js files          
      $jsFiles = $js->addFiles('calendar');

      foreach ($jsFiles as $k=>$file){
           $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/' . $file.'.js');
      }


    }
```

And in the layout.phtml:

```
<?php
 echo $this->doctype()."\n";
 ?>
 <html>
    <head>
       <?php
         echo $this->headMeta()."\n";
         echo $this->headLink()."\n";
         echo $this->headTitle()."\n";
         echo $this->headScript()."\n";
```

Comment: You want to add JS files to the layout yet you've disabled the layout?

Comment: The layout is enabled in IndexController. The other Controllers have the layout disabled.

Comment: And is it the index controller from which you want to add JS files, if so see Subdigger's answer; if not, my question above still stands.

Comment: The other Controllers are loading different views for which I need different js files.

Comment: @Time Fountain: I finally understood what did you mean by "You want to add JS files to the layout yet you've disabled the layout?". What I want can't be solved this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go by this way:
in controller

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile(
          '/js/prototype.js',
          'text/javascript',
          array('conditional' => 'lt IE 7')
        );
    }
......
}
```

then in view:

```
.....
  <head>
    <?php echo $this->headScript() ?>
  </head>
.....
```

read [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Comment: It's not working. As I said, I have disabled the layout in that Controller so using '$this->view' it's useless. At least that is why I think it's not working.

Comment: @sica07 even if you disable layout - view renders

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem but not your intentions correctly. You say in a comment that the layout is enabled in the indexController but the others have the layout disabled. If you dispatch to another controller and disable the layout the layout.phtml should not be used. So, how do you use it? Do you have an include somewhere?

I think the solution here is not to disable the layout but to load a different layout in those "other" controllers.

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('foobaz');
```

You can load a different layout for each controller or even action in a controller. Another thing I noticed is that you load it in the init() method. I do all this logic in the actions or pre/postDispatch methods.

Comment: Yes, you're very right. I'm not using it in the other controllers. I have to think at a different approach. I didn't knew that I can enable a different layout. thanks for the idea, but I don't think that this is what I need

Comment: Glad to help a little. If we knew what your intention is with disabling the layout we could have helped more.

Comment: The idea is that the other Controllers are controlling different Views. I thought that it is a good solution to load it only once (with the IndexController).

Comment: Controllers with a few exceptions are more or less independent structures. You cannot assign one thing in one controller and assume this is available in another controller. Also watch out for **view** versus **layout**. These are methodically two different constructs in ZF.